# Eclipse not calling sub-makefiles correctly

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, arm

I am trying to refactor a single makefile project to hierarchical structure. The project is imported in Eclipse as "External C/C++ project with makefile".

The new folder with the separate makefile contains source files and a makefile with the following recipe:

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    echo "test"
```

The top directory contains a the top-level makefile with the following recipe:

```
clean:
    @ echo ...cleaning
    cd CppAudioPeriphs && make test
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(NAME).lst $(NAME).elf $(NAME).bin $(NAME).s19 $(NAME).map $(NAME).dmp
```

When I call from Eclipse `Clean project`, the last line from the last recipie clearly completes correctly. However, the line, asking to go to the sub-directory and execute `make clean` returns with the following message:

```
make[1]: `build/PeriphPhysical.o' is up to date.
```

This is the first object file declared, and the message is the same even if recipe `test` does not exist.

On the other hand, from the command line, everything works. Id est open `cmd.exe`, go to project folder, type `make clean` - > the "echo test" command gets executed.

I am using gcc and binutils, compiled for Windows, for cross-compilation for arm. Where could be my problem.

---

EDIT: response to *jimmy*

These may be additional clues.

1) If I replace

```
    cd CppAudioPeriphs && "make test"
```

with

```
    cd CppAudioPeriphs && C:\arm_tools\tools\bin\make.exe test
```

, the result is:

```
/usr/bin/sh: C:arm_toolstoolsbinmake.exe: command not found
```

If I change the slashes to forward slashes, the old message of ``build/PeriphPhysical.o' is up to date.` pops back in.

Comment: I would have look at your file and directory paths. It might be that eclipse copied some files (as it sometimes do) when you exported your project and your make files are now refering to the wrong copy.

Comment: @jimmy, see my edit. Any idea what kind of files should I be looking at ("copied some files")?

Comment: Hmm, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4909512/1145760) might be connected to my problem. I'll try to add some more absolute paths.

Comment: Aha, could be. Also I see that you are using a backslash in your path. I am not sure eclipse can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced

```
cd CppAudioPeriphs && C:\arm_tools\tools\bin\make.exe test
```

with

```
make -C CppAudioPeriphs test
```

as a workaround and now everything compiles.